# Auto merge in Mercurial

Tags: git, mercurial, merge

I'm sort of new to HG, but I've used Git for a while.

Desired behavior:
In Git, if I commit a change to a file on computer A, commit a change to the same file (but in a different area of the file) on computer B, and pull the changes from A to B, it will automatically merge and everything is fine.

What's happening:
In HG, when I pull computer A's changes to computer B, it opens up some 3 paned merging tool, despite the fact that the changes shouldn't conflict with each other. When I try to close of the merging tool (it's not very user friendly, I have no idea how to use it), it saves the version computer B has, ignoring computer A's changes.

Comment: Try the CLI, it's user friendly :).

Answer (score 2):

What merging tool are you using? And are you sure the merging tool does not report any conflicting changes?

From my experience with the mercurial, the behavior you state as desired is actually the standard behavior.

Comment: I agree, in my experience, Hg is only going to call up the external merge tool when it needs too. Are you sure there were no conflicts?

Comment: Me too - do you have line ending differences?

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseHG global (or repository) settings - "TortoiseHG" tab (first from top), latest radio-group "Auto-resolve merges". Select "YES" instead of default "NO" - and **in case of non-crossing changes** merge will happens behind the scene

[image]